# TextField in material-ui: can a class be passed to errorStyle?

Tags: material-ui

Can I put a class to the errorStyle property of TextField?

i.e

```
import styles from './example.scss';
<TextField {...properties} errorStyle={styles.inputError} />
```

Answer (score 0):

No. material-ui doesn't allows that. Whenever there's a props like errorClassName then only you can pass in the class name